# NodeJS testing writeFile with mock-fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking

For example, I have the following file:

**spec/config/file-mock.js**

```
var mock = require('mock-fs');
mock({
  'files': {
    'expense.csv': 'a;b;c;d\n1;2;3;4\n5;6;7;8'
  }
});
```

**app/reader/reader.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var reader = {
    read: function(path) {
        return fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');
    },
    write: function(path, object) {
        fs.writeFileSync(path, object);
    }
};
module.exports = reader;
```

**app/reader/reader.spec.js**

```
describe('reader.js test', function(){
    var reader = require('./reader.js');
    var mock = require('mock-fs');
    it('should return a simple string', function(){
        expect(reader.read('files/expense.csv')).toEqual('a;b;c;d\n1;2;3;4\n5;6;7;8');
    });
    it('should write a json object', function(){
        // WHAT TO DO?!
    });
});
```

The `reader.read` function is working fine with [mock-fs](https://github.com/tschaub/mock-fs).

But I'm trying to test the `reader.write` function and I didn't found anything in the documentation about the "write" functions. Anyone already solved this?

Comment: did you try just doing a reader.write, then doing an expect on reader.read?

   `reader.write('/temp/foo.txt', 'bar'); 
   expect(reader.read('temp/foo.txt').toEqual('bar')`

Comment: I was facing the same issue until I found your comment. Mock-fs mocks the entire fs module so when you write, you are not really writing on your system but in the mock-fs object.

Answer (score 1):

As @Strech posted in comments you might try an expect on reader.read after calling reader.write to check that the content has been written to the fake file.

IMHO there is a better way to test this functionality out a bit more stick to unit test principles. We know that **fs** module works because is part of node core modules and it's tested there, so we can mock **fs** methods and instead check that those methods are being called with the expected parameters, for instance using [Sinon](https://sinonjs.org/):

```
const Reader = require('../reader.js');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const fs = require('fs');
const expect = require('expect.js');

describe('reader.js test', function () {

  let readFileSync;
  let writeFileSync;

  beforeEach(() => {
    readFileSync = sinon.stub(fs, 'readFileSync').returns({});
    writeFileSync = sinon.stub(fs, 'writeFileSync').returns({});
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    readFileSync.restore();
    writeFileSync.restore();
  });

  it('should return a simple string', () => {

    Reader.read('files/expense.csv');
    expect(readFileSync.calledOnceWith('files/expense.csv', 'utf8')).to.be(true);
  });

  it('should write a json object', () => {

    Reader.write('files/expense.csv', 'test');
    expect(writeFileSync.calledOnceWith('files/expense.csv', 'test')).to.be(true);
  });
});
```